# Java Client accessing .net WCF service

Tags: java, .net, wcf, soap

I have a method wriiten in WCF service which accepts a parameter of type Stream.

```
TestUpload(Stream fileStream);
```

When it is accessed by Java client getting the following error:

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [SoapUi](http://www.soapui.org/)? It can be helpful during WCF services testing.